# Basic php file linked to html file

Tags: php, html

Hi I know to some of you this is a very basic question but I am really struggling with it as i have just recently started using php files. I am trying to figure out why my html page wont print the desired output.

HTML page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset='utf-8' />
     <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
       <?php

          include 'pTest.php';
          print $num;
       ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

PHP file code:

```
<?php

   $num = 1;

?>
```

Comment: You can't put PHP code in HTML files.

Comment: If you want you can rename your .html file into .php

Answer (score 1):

Your server is not configured to look in `.html` files for PHP directives. The content between `<?php` and `?>` will be sent to the browser instead of being executed.

Give both files a `.php` file extension. Make sure you load them through a web server that supports PHP.